# ALTER TABLE to Add a column doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE New_Column
        @table_name varchar(25),
        @column_name varchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @mySql nvarchar (MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @mySql = 'ALTER TABLE '+@table_name+' ADD '+@column_name+' INT'
    EXEC (@mySql)
END
```

And this code in Visual Studio, using VB.Net and web forms

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web

Public Class Add_Column
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public strConn As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EECRDashboard;Integrated Security=True"
    Private sqlCon As SqlConnection

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SelectTableName()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SelectTableName()
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Try
                sqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConn)
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader
                Using (sqlCon)
                    Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand()

                    sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon

                    sqlComm.CommandText = "SelectTableName"
                    sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                    sqlCon.Open()
                    reader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
                    cboTableName.DataSource = reader
                    cboTableName.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME"
                    cboTableName.DataValueField = "TABLE_NAME"
                    cboTableName.DataBind()
                    Dim Period As String = cboTableName.SelectedValue
                    sqlCon.Close()

                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If 
    End Sub

    Protected Sub cboTableName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboTableName.SelectedIndexChanged
        SelectTableName()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Insert_Column()
        Try
            sqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConn)
            Using (sqlCon)

                Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand()

                sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon
                sqlCon.Open()
                sqlComm.CommandText = "New_Column"
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@column_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtColumnName.Text()
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@table_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cboTableName.SelectedValue.ToString)
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                sqlCon.Close()

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception 
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btbSaveColumn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btbSaveColumn.Click
        Insert_Column()
    End Sub       
End Class
```

Buuut, when I click the button it doesn't create the column. And when I make tests in SQL Server Management Studio, it works!

I don't know what the problem is.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using SQLite?

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint on your code and it runs ?

Comment: Why are you converting your table name to an integer - `Convert.ToInt32(cboTableName.SelectedValue.ToString)`?

Comment: Why do you need a procedure to add columns to a table? Do you make table changes that frequently? If so I would venture to say there are some serious issues with the architecture.

Comment: I think, you need to switch parameters in your code. I believe they are by order not by name. Another inconsistency is, you do `Convert.ToInt32` to a table name. This just doesn't make sense

Comment: @Mark I can't believe it. That was the thing. Thank you!

Comment: @SeanLange in fact is a requirement, the customer wants that.

Comment: Often times the customer asks for things they don't fully understand. I have a feeling this may be one of those. Allowing for schema modifications at will is a recipe for disaster. I wish you the best of luck with this system.